# How to change the names of the layers of deep learning in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am using **vgg16** to create a deep learning model. I want to know **how to change the names of the layers of deep learning in Keras?**

I tried this

```
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    layer.name = layer.name + str("_")
```

But when I change the names of the layers, **the model accuracy become low**.

Comment: Have you seen [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6194)?

Comment: Changing the string `name` attribute of a layer should not affect the accuracy of a model. They are simply descriptors.

Comment: Thanks @Media, I saw the link, but the problem is little different.

Answer (score 10):

I made a small example, which basically does the same as your code, and I show that the expected results are obtained:

#### Imports

```
In [1]: from keras.models import Sequential
In [2]: from keras.layers import Dense
```

### Build a model

Note the `name` arguments:

```
In [3]: model = Sequential()
In [4]: model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(20, 20), name='dense1'))
In [5]: model.add(Dense(30, name='dense2'))
In [6]: model.add(Dense(1, name='dense3'))
In [7]: model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
In [8]: model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense1 (Dense)               (None, 20, 50)            1050      
_________________________________________________________________
dense2 (Dense)               (None, 20, 30)            1530      
_________________________________________________________________
dense3 (Dense)               (None, 20, 1)             31        
=================================================================
```

### Rename the layers

EDIT: it seems newer versions of Keras and the `tf.keras` API now do not allow renaming layers via `layer.name = "new_name"`. Instead you must assign your new name to the *private* attribute, `layer._name`.

```
In [9]: for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    ...:     # layer.name = 'layer_' + str(i)    <-- old way
    ...:     layer._name = 'layer_' + str(i)
In [10]: model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
layer_0 (Dense)              (None, 20, 50)            1050      
_________________________________________________________________
layer_1 (Dense)              (None, 20, 30)            1530      
_________________________________________________________________
layer_2 (Dense)              (None, 20, 1)             31        
=================================================================
```

So we see the layers now have the new names!

### Further inspection

I can see that the internal identifiers of the layers themselves **are not changed**. I show the first layer's weights, as we see the original label is still present:

```
In [11]: a = model.layers[0]
In [12]: a.weights
Out[12]: 
[<tf.Variable 'dense1/kernel:0' shape=(20, 50) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense1/bias:0' shape=(50,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

We see the `dense1` name is still visible in the layer container, along with its unchanged shape and datatype.

I also initialised the model weights by running `model.get_weights()`, then renamed the layers as before to new names, compiled the model and saw that the layers' names were altered as before, and the weights themselves were not changed i.e. reinitialised. The exact same values were contained. This means that renaming your layers cannot be behind the drop in accuracy.

Comment: I am using vgg16..... In my case, the weights and the structures of the model before and after changing the names are same. But the performance is different. It is strange :/

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49550182/9214357).

You need to use:
`layer._name = layer.name + str('asdf')`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is caused by not correctly load pre-trained weights. Check if you use `model.load_weights` with `by_name=True`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code.

```
def model1_VGG16():
    vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
    vgg16._name = 'VGG16_1'
    model = Sequential()  
    model.add(vgg16)
    ...
    return model

def model2_VGG16():
    vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
    vgg16._name = 'VGG16_2'
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(vgg16)
    ...
    return model
```